# Lua (Command Line) remain open after execution

Tags: command-line, lua

I have searched far and wide for this but I cannot seem to find it.  Is there any way to execute a `Lua` script via double clicking it (to execute it in `Lua (Command Line)`) and keep it open after execution?

For example:

```
print("Hello World")
```

This code compiles and runs, however if I double click on `hello.lua`it runs and closes immediately without leaving my text on screen.  I want something more like this, but without having to go to `Command Prompt`, changing directory a bunch of times, typing `lua file.lua`, etc.:

[image: Command Prompt]

Comment: Search windows registry for invocation string on double-clicking .lua-file and change it to something like `cmd.exe /K lua.exe "%1"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just add a 'pause' at the end of your script:

```
print 'Hello World'
os.execute 'pause'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution is not cross-platform. `pause` does not exist in every shell.

Comment: Good to know!  Luckily I'm working on Windows XP so its a perfect solution.

Answer (score 11):

Add [io.read()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.read) at the end of your script.