# How to run an executable from lua?

Tags: lua, executable, nlua

I am trying to start an executable by **lua**. Lua function is called in a thread by c#. `os.execute` starts a `.bat` file, which is kept at the same location as the program but not able to start the program.

```
os.execute('D:/startApplication.bat')
os.execute('D:/application.exe')
```

The top line works while the bottom one doesn't.

This question differs from [How do I run an executable using Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829404/how-do-i-run-an-executable-using-lua) because I am using lua in .net environment. And solution given in that question is not working for me.

Comment: This is the method. If you can run a .bat and not the .exe, it still means you have using the correct way of running an executable. Why the .exe file is "not working" is probably not linked with lua directly. As a complete guess, I would say it might be Windows preventing arbitrary exe file to be executed, or a problem of current working directory needed by application.exe. Try to run your LUA program (or Visual Studio / your IDE) as an administrator, to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Also, how can you say that "it doesn't work" ? Do you get an exception ? other error ? (please share the message). Or you get simply... nothing ? (maybe application.exe does actually nothing in this context...).

Comment: There was no error or exception. A command prompt window open up and close itself within 2 seconds. Behaviour is same even if I am running application with administrator right.

Comment: Could you check here to see if the "window closing too quick" hides an error message : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071956/lua-command-line-remain-open-after-execution

Comment: Or is it the actual application.exe window ? Can you check if opening manually yoursels (by typing `D:\application.exe` in a command prompt) yields something different ?

Comment: adding ```os.execute('pause')``` still close the window quickly. And if i write D:\application.exe in command prompt, the program starts.

Comment: As i said, if i start a ```.bat``` file  from lua and start that application in batch file then it run perfectly. But i want to avoid use of batch file.